# sigprocmask() issue

Tags: c, linux, signals

The code below is from the book *Advanced programming in unix environment*, W. Richard Stevens

And about this code book says;

> "If the signal is sent to the process while it is blocked, the signal delivery will be deferred until the signal is unblocked. To the application, this can look as if the signal occurs between the unblocking and the pause (depending on how the kernel implements signals). If this happens, or if the signal does occur between the unblocking and the pause, we have a problem. Any occurrence of the signal in this window of time is lost in the sense that we might not see the signal again, in which case the pause  will block indefinitely. This is another problem with the earlier unreliable signals."

And it recommands to use `sigsuspend()` before resetting signal mask instead of `pause()` since it resets the signal mask and put the process to sleep in a single atomic operation. But I don't want my process wait until signal came after stepping out of critical region. **So is this problem valid for my case too?** If so what should i use not to lose signal while reseting signal mask with `sigprocmask()`?

```
 sigset_t     newmask, oldmask;

  sigemptyset(&newmask);
  sigaddset(&newmask, SIGINT);

  /* block SIGINT and save current signal mask */
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_BLOCK error");

  /* critical region of code */

  /* reset signal mask, which unblocks SIGINT */
  if (sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldmask, NULL) < 0)
      err_sys("SIG_SETMASK error");

  /* window is open */
  pause();  /* wait for signal to occur */

  /* continue processing */
```

Comment: You haven't really made clear what your question is. Do you have a critical region of code? What is your case?

Comment: My code similiar to the above code without a pause() but other my own functions. Between two sigprocmask() call is my critical region like above code but in my case all the above code is in a while(1) loop. So i want my signal handler to work just when program execution goes out of critical region and if signal(it is a SIGALRM) is delivered.

Comment: You could use sigpending() to lookup pending signal before calling sigprocmask() to unlock signals, but this seems to be a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

sigsuspend is used in order to avoid a course between sigprocmask and pause.  If you don't need to halt your thread until a signal is received, there is nothing sigsuspend can do for you.  You don't give enough information to know if there are other sources of trouble in your context or not.